# Dynamically adding multiple custom directives associated with single controller in angularjs 1

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have an html template attached to a controller and three directives. There are three buttons. On clicking a button a directive is added to the page(using ng-click) like this(the following is in my controller not in directive):

```
$scope.addFilterDimension = function() {
console.log('CLICKED!!!!!!!')
var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#filterDimension'));
var appendHtml = $compile('<filter-directive></filter-directive>')($scope);
divElement.append(appendHtml);
}
```

Similarly for other buttons, other directives are added. Now, I can keep adding as many of these directives as I like, which is the use case here. 
These directives are basically like forms containing either dropdowns, input boxes or both. The values user selects from the dropdowns or enters in input boxes have to be sent back to the backend to be stored in the DB.
This is one of the directives(others are very similar):

```
anomalyApp.directive('filterDirective', function() {
return {
restrict: "E",
scope: {},
templateUrl:'filter-dimension.html',
controller: function($rootScope, $scope, $element) {
  $scope.dimensionsOld = $rootScope.dimensionsOld;
  $scope.dimensions = $rootScope.dimensions;
  $scope.selectedDimensionName = $rootScope.selectedDimensionName;
  $scope.selectedDimensionValue = $rootScope.selectedDimensionValue;     
  $scope.extend = $rootScope.extend;
  $scope.selectedExtend = $rootScope.selectedExtend;

  $scope.isDateField = $rootScope.isDateField;

  console.log($scope.dimensions);
  $scope.Delete = function(e) {
    //remove element and also destoy the scope that element
    $element.remove();
    $scope.$destroy();
  }
  }
 }
});
```

Now, in my controller I assign $rootscope to my values which have to be used in the directives and thus catch them in the directive. Example:

```
 $rootScope.dimensions = temp.map(d=>d.dimName);
 $rootScope.selectedDimensionName = '';
 $rootScope.selectedDimensionValue = '';
```

And this is how I retrieve my values from added directives:

```
var retriveValue = function() {
var filtersData = [];
var constraintsData = [];
var variablesData = [];
var ChildHeads = [$scope.$$childHead];
var currentScope;
while (ChildHeads.length) {
  currentScope = ChildHeads.shift();
  while (currentScope) {
    if (currentScope.dimensions !== undefined){
      filtersData.push({
        filterDimensionName: currentScope.selectedDimensionName,
        filterDimensionValue: currentScope.selectedDimensionValue,
        filterDimensionExtend: currentScope.selectedExtend,
        filterDimensionIsDateFiled: currentScope.isDateField
      });
    }
      if (currentScope.constraintDimensions !== undefined){
        filtersData.push({
        constraintDimensionName: currentScope.selectedConstraintName,
        constraintDimensionValue: currentScope.selectedConstraintValue,
        constraintDimensionExtend: currentScope.selectedConstraintExtend,
        constraintDimensionVariable: currentScope.selectedConstraintVariable,
        constraintDimensionOperator: currentScope.selectedOperator,
        constraintDimensionVariableValue: currentScope.constraintVariableValue,
        constraintDimensionIsDateField: currentScope.isDateFieldConstraint
      });
    }
      if (currentScope.variableNames !== undefined){
        console.log('currentScope.selectedVariableVariable',currentScope.selectedVariableVariable);
      filtersData.push({
        variableName: currentScope.selectedVariableVariable,
        variableOperator: currentScope.selectedVariableOperator,
        variableValue: currentScope.variableVariableValue,
        variableExtend: currentScope.selectedVariableExtend
      });
    }

    currentScope = currentScope.$$nextSibling;
  }
}
return filtersData;
}
```

This is one of the directive's template:

```
<div >
<div>
  <label>Dimension</label>  
  <select class = "custom-select custom-select-lg mb-6" ng-model="selectedDimensionName" ng-options="dimension for dimension in dimensions">
      <!-- <option ng-repeat="table in tables track by $index">{{table}}</option> -->
  </select>
</div>


<div>
    <label>Date Field</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isDateField">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Value</label>
  <select multiple class = "custom-select custom-select-lg mb-6" ng-model="selectedDimensionValue" ng-options="val for val in ((dimensionsOld | filter:{'dimName':selectedDimensionName})[0].dimValues)"></select>
  </span>
</div>


<div>
    <label>Extend</label>
    <select class = "custom-select custom-select-lg mb-6" ng-model="selectedExtend" ng-options="val for val in extend"></select>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" ng-click="Delete($event)">Delete</button>
```

This is in the main html to add the directive:

```
<div id="filterDimension">    </div>
```

I know this is not a good way, but please suggest a better one.
Secondly, a new change has to be made where inside one of the directives there will be a button, clicking on which 2 dropdowns(or simply one more directive) will be added and can be added as many times as needed(just like the other directive).
The issue here is this one is a directive inside another directive and I am facing unusual behavior like:

1. When I add the parent directive it is fine, I add the child directives its fine, but when I add a second parent and try to add its child, they get appended inside the first directive.
2. Even if I somehow manage to get out of the above point I do not know how to retrieve values from such directives.

PS: I am new in AngularJS or front-end for that matter, the retriveValue() and using rootscope I got from somewhere online.